# Ubuntu 18.04 unable to use projector

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have Ubuntu 18.04 installed on a laptop with an attached projector. Using Open office I can display presentations on the projector. Videos will not display on the projector. What driver or other software do I need to display videos on the projector? I have only just started using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Using the projector, you are using two different screens. Libreoffice automatically displays the presentation on the secondary screen. Other applications play where you launch them. To have your video appear on the secondary screen (projector), move the application there and start the video.

In Settings - Displays, you can see the current layout of your screens (and you can optionally change it there). Typically, your secondary screen will be on the right, and is to be seen as extended area of your current screen. So if you drag an application to the right it will start appearing on the projector screen.

A faster way to move an application to another screen is by pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow keys</kbd>.

Comment: Now able to move to projector but have lost audio on both laptop & projector. Have installed pavucontrol but still no audio.

Comment: Fixed  - Audio muted on laptop.

Comment: Did this answer help?